# Обновление данных в Label(Tkinter)

Tags: python-3.x, ооп, tkinter, sqlite3

Есть 4 функции, по типу той, что снизу, они берут столбцы из SQL таблицы и возвращают сумму их значений:

```
def get_total_tournament():
    """Выбирает данные из колонки tournament_name 
    и возвращает сумму значений всех ячеек в колонке"""
    with connect(file_path) as connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(tournament_name) FROM statistics')
        sum_result = cursor.fetchone()[0]
        if sum_result:
            return sum_result
        else:
            return 0
```

Есть класс, который инициализирует виджет label:

```
class MyLabel:
    def __init__(self, window, text, x, y, font):
        self.window = window
        self.text = text
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.font = font
        self.label = tk.Label(self.window, text=self.text, font=self.font)
        self.label.place(x=self.x, y=self.y)
```

Так же есть переменные с объектами класса MyLabel в них поступают переменные, в которых находятся вызовы функций(по типу той, что указана выше):

```
money_spent_1 = MyLabel(basic_window, f"{total_money_win} $", 160, 135, 'Times 15') 
total_tournament_1 = MyLabel(basic_window, total_tournament, 435, 135, 'Times 15') 
total_gain_1 = MyLabel(basic_window, f"{total_money_lose} $", 180, 170, 'Times 15') 
total_buy_in_1= MyLabel(basic_window, total_buy_in, 430, 170, 'Times 15')
```

Как сделать так, чтобы данные в этих Label постоянно обновлялись ? Без необходимости перезапускать программу ?